# Angular2 Declaring a directive's selector to require a text input

Tags: html, angular

I have just created a number directive :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][number]'
})
export class NumberDirective  {...}
```

I would like my selector to be even more specific and requires a text input :

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="..." [number]="...">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attribute selectors with value

```
selector: 'input[type="text"][ngModel][number]'
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors